# Detect if an action was made by other trigger SQL SERVER?

Tags: sql-server, triggers, sql-server-2014

I'm using SQL SERVER 2014.

I have a `table` where it has 2 triggers (`for update`).

Trigger 1 - updates columns `A`. (which causes Trigger 2 to be invoked)

Trigger 2 - updates columns `B`. (which causes Trigger 1 to be invoked)

**Question:**

Within a trigger - is it possible to  identify that the current update was triggered via a Trigger ?

Example :

1- User updated the table
2- Trigger 1 updates column A
3 -Trigger 2 invoked due to step 2.
4 - within Trigger 2 - is there any code that can detect that update was made via trigger in step2 ?

Comment: add a field to the table and update it in trigger 1. Than trigger 2 can read that field

Comment: @GuidoG Nice work around  - but adding an indication columns for all of my tables (~500) seems problematic.... :-)

Comment: Does column A only gets updated by trigger 1 .? If so than you can check in trigger 2 if inserted.A is different than deleted.A

Comment: @GuidoG No . it can also be updated via the  App itself. I jsut want to prevent recursion of updated for those two sibling triggers. something like (within trigger 2) - `If triggered_via_trigger() return`

Comment: Then I dont have answer for you. I dont think it is possible, good luck

Comment: @GuidoG Apprently there's a solution. I'm reading it  now . https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/trigger-nestlevel-transact-sql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try using `CONTEXT_INFO()`?

```
ALTER TRIGGER test1
   ON table
   AFTER UPDATE
AS 
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    IF NOT UPDATE(x)
        RETURN;

    DECLARE @ci varbinary(128) = CAST('Trigger=' + cast(OBJECT_NAME(@@PROCID) AS varchar(128)) + REPLICATE(' ', 128) as varbinary(128));
    SET CONTEXT_INFO @ci;

    UPDATE table
        SET a = 1
        WHERE id = 1;

    SET CONTEXT_INFO 0x0; -- clear
END
GO

alter TRIGGER test2
   ON table
   AFTER UPDATE
AS 
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    IF NOT UPDATE(a)
        RETURN;

    DECLARE @ci varchar(128) = (SELECT CAST(CONTEXT_INFO() AS varchar) FROM master.dbo.SYSPROCESSES WHERE spid = @@SPID);
    DECLARE @log varchar(2048) = CONCAT('CALLER:', @ci);
    EXEC xp_logevent 60000, @log, informational;

    -- update b
END
GO
```

This give me log message:

```
Date        19.09.2017 18:31:21
Log     SQL Server (Current - 19.09.2017 18:29:00)

Source      spid74

Message
CALLER:Trigger=test1
```

Comment: What's  UPDATE(c)?

Comment: `UPDATE(c)` return `true` if column `c` was updated. p.s. please, check last edit - I added one needful `cast`

Comment: Yes, as you wrote: `3 -Trigger 2 invoked due to step 2.`

Comment: Anyway there's another solution kf nestjng level. Ols see my comment to my question. Btw i didn't know about context info. Thanks